# Difference between Admin and Manager role in Tomcat6

Tags: centos, tomcat, tomcat6

What are the roles `admin` and `manager` used for in Tomcat6?

The `manager` role appears to give me access to `http://domain.com:8080/manager/html`. Which page does the `admin` role give me?

In the file, the description for `admin` role is pretty vague. What is the `host manager webapp`?

```
<!-- The host manager webapp is restricted to users with role "admin" -->
<!--<user name="tomcat" password="password" roles="admin" />-->
<!-- The manager webapp is restricted to users with role "manager" -->
<!--<user name="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager" />-->
```